# Series Whose Protagonist Is a Leper

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I am trying to remember a series I read some time ago (probably in the early aughts) about a leper who is transported to another world where he leads an army. In the real world, he cannot feel most of his limbs, but in this new world he suffers no such effects. I don't remember many details, but I believe he is accused of raping a pretty important female character early in the timeline. There were three books.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Thomas_Covenant

Comment: Love the new username! Haven't seen much of you since the Aiel Waste and the battle of Cairhien.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### *The Chronicles of Thomas Covenant, the Unbeliever.*

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Thomas_Covenant), here's a one-sentence summary of the series:

> Thomas Covenant, an embittered and cynical writer, afflicted with leprosy and shunned by society, is fated to become the heroic savior of The Land, an alternate world.

Early on in [the first book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Foul's_Bane):

> Covenant refuses to accept the reality of the Land. Appalled and indignant at the expectations the people of the Land have for him as their new-found saviour, he gives himself the title of "Unbeliever." He is also unprepared for **the sudden restoration of his health**, which cures the impotence brought on by his leprosy. This, and his mental turmoil over the reality he feels but does not believe, drives him into a frenzy, **causing him to rape Lena, an act which will be pivotal to all that follows.**

There are three books in the first trilogy, but it's also followed by a second trilogy, *The Second Chronicles of Thomas Covenent*, and a tetralogy, *The Last Chronicles of Thomas Covenant*, making for a total of **ten books**.